# How to create Anchor Tag in react-router?

Tags: react-router, anchor, react-boilerplate

I am using react-boilerplate (3.4.0) with react-router internally for the routing.

I have tried to create a Link with : < a href="#anchor-tag" >< /a >

When I click on it I expect to scroll to the div with `id=anchor-tag`

It just scroll to the top of the page, even if I use a Link component instead of a < A > tag. Does we have to care about use < A > or < Link > ?

How should we create anchor tag in react-router ?

Answer (score 3):

This might be a while late but what you can do is add this to your component:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

... some more codez...

componentDidUpdate() {
  const anchor = this.props.location.hash.replace('#', '');

  if (anchor) {
    const domElement = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs[hash]);
    if (domElement) {
      domElement.scrollIntoView();
    }
  }
}
```

and then on your actual element that you want to navigate to, you need to add the `ref` attribute, like this:

```
<h1 ref="my-anchor">Hello World</h1>
```

The link element is going to look just like a regular link:

```
<a href="/about#my-anchor>Go To Anchor</a>
```

Or with react-router:

```
<Link key="my-anchor" to="/about#my-anchor">Go To Anchor</Link>
```

This works with react-router 2.6.1 - not sure about later versions at this point.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it will help, i will try it and tell you if its working for me asap.

Answer (score 1):

Improved answer above:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const anchor = this.props.location.hash;

  if (anchor) {
    const domElement = document.querySelector(anchor);
    if (domElement) {
      domElement.scrollIntoView();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to use the package from [Rafael Pedicini](https://github.com/rafrex) called [react-router-hash-link](https://github.com/rafrex/react-router-hash-link).

Live example right [there](http://react-router-hash-link.rafrex.com/). It's working well and the code is clean.