# How to use anchor id tag history in react.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

I found some answer that state we can use `hash` for this problem but I can't use it since it will make my web link doesn't look good. What I want is to navigate user when they clicked some section in the same page in my web for example when you clicked `about` then the link will look like `base_url/home#about`.

Normally i can use it in normal html such as like this simple line `<a href="#about">about</a>` but I'm quite loss how to use it inside DOM or at least in reactjs. I already try to solve it around 10 days but still no luck.

this is some article that I read but I think it too old:

[use-anchors-with-react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280369/use-anchors-with-react-router)

[how-to-create-anchor-tag-in-react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41739847/how-to-create-anchor-tag-in-react-router)

can someone help to solved this? I'm quite confused about this problem.

just for reference this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "base",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "history": "^4.9.0",
    "mdbreact": "^4.18.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^1.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "react-scrollable-anchor": "^0.6.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

This is the example when I using `hashlink`

```
import { HashLink as Links } from 'react-router-hash-link';

<Links to="#about">test</Links>
```

this is my homepage component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// Component
import './homepage.css';
import Header from '../header/header';
import Footer from '../footer/footer';
import Carousel from './carousel/carousel';
import Banner from './banner/banner'
import Pesanan from './pesanan/pesanan';
import Value from './value/value';
import About from './about/about';
import Order from './order/order';
import Klien from './klien/klien';
import Portfolio from './portfolio/portfolio';

class Homepage extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="body">
        <Header />
        <Carousel id="promotion-banner" />
        <Banner />          
        <Pesanan id="status" />
        <Value id="value" />
        <About id="about" />
        <Order id="order" />
        <Klien id="client" />
        <Portfolio id="portfolio" />
        <Footer id="contact" />
      </div>
    );  
  }
}

export default Homepage;
```

This is my app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

// Components
import './App.css';
import Homepage from './Components/homepage/homepage';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I don't get why you have a problem with this, the first answer from the links you provided states that you  can use `import { HashLink as Link } from 'react-router-hash-link';` and then just declare it as `<Link to="home-page#section-three">Section three</Link>`

Comment: @ZombieChowder thankyou for your response, when I try to use `hashlink` i can routing normally but still failed when using id `<Links to="#about">test</Links>` this is what I try and this is the id tag that I used in component `<About id="about" />`